# MarkerCluster in Leaflet is not defined?

Tags: typescript, webpack, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I've made short animation to show the issue.

[image]

As You can see I'm using `leaflet@1.5.1` with `markercluster@1.4.1` and typescript and `webpack@4.30.0`.

On page refresh markers are added. But when I hover it throws an error saying that `L.MarkerCluster` does not exist. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Thw issue was with `webpack` configuration. Webpack was splitting `leaflet` and `leaflet.markercluter` to two files. That's why `L` was not defined.

I had to add to `plugins` in `webpack.config`

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        "L": 'leaflet',
        "window.L": 'leaflet',
    }),
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me :( can please help me with that?